# Строчная или прописная?

Tags: оформление-текста

Ситуация такая. Пишется некий текст, после которого ставится точка. Следующим предложением идет адрес, начинающийся с города. Например, "г. Киев и т.д.". Нужно ли тут писать сокращение "г." (город) с прописной буквы? По логике, после точки должны быть именно она, но как-то некрасиво выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я присоединяюсь. Довольно странный текст вы описываете, только догадываться остаётся. И адрес в виде отдельного предложения как-то странно выглядит в сплошном тексте. 
А вообще я не помню, чтобы этот случай где-то специально оговаривался. На практике, знаю, возможен такой примерно случай. 
*Мой адрес: "г. Город, ул. Улица...".*  
Тут против всех правил сокращение в начале фразы - со строчной. 
Но на конвертах пишут именно так, так что вроде как это точная цитата и строчная "г" оправдана.

Единственное, что приходит на ум по аналогии, это написание французских, скажем, фамилий с "де/д'" или немецких с "фон" и т.п. в начале фразы. Помню копьеломательную полемику по этому поводу лет двадцать пять назад, решили, что в русском всё-таки следует писать с заглавной. Если с тех пор ничего не изменилось, то наверное, все-таки и "г." в вашем случае с заглавной.

Comment: Ничего странного. Это рекламное объявление в газете.

Comment: Тогда точно - со строчной. В объявлениях, сколько бы мы ни возмущались, понятийная сторона важнее правильнописательной. Тем более тут вопрос не совсем орфографический, скорее - оформление текста.

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя слово город написать полностью? Приведите контекст. пожалуйста, чтобы был понятен хотя бы стиль.